# Tool for editing .X

Tags: directx

I am trying to use .X files (whoa.. huh? lol), but I found no good software for importing .X files then editing them then exporting them.. all this with animations, all this in text format (optional, but would be great), all this with having multiple meshes in one .X file. Found some good software to do the half of the jobs done, but is there any way to do it in one step? (I mean really - what do other programmers use at all? I found no good stuff on net.. am I to implement one myself, or such?)

So any good suggestion would be great, and without garbage: .X files in text with animations with multiple meshes to import and then edit and then export.

Thanks:
Péter

*edit: I already tried Blender. The 2.49b was the last version supporting import directx in text. After these versions blender is not even importing .x, only exports. 2.49b can export animated .x, but can not import animation. 2.49b can export multiple meshes but will only import one of the meshes - from the same export it did (unmodified). Thanks for the suggestion, but blender is no solution for this, unless you can suggest a working script too please?*

**solution:** for above mentioned problem there were some solutions. Here I try to sum up stuff:

- Blender is a partially working solution; see edit above.
- Milkshape seemed to work with directx files, but for my tests it showed up, that only preview worked well, on main screen the textures were bad and no animations were imported. Versions checked are: 1.7.0 and 1.8.4 or something like that, I don't remember.
- TrueSpace seemed to not work for any of the .X files. No idea why; tried with tiny.x provided by the DirectX SDK, but nope.
  *- Good solution is to use quick converter - see post bellow, marked as good answer. Found this allright, because it is closest to my goal.
- Found a program (**UU3D** - Ultimate Unwrap 3D) that loads .X well, with more meshes and multiple animations and the textures are just fine too. Because it is not free, I could not try that if it can save with text as well (saving is simply disabled in demo). For those, who can afford such I could only recommend, because it looks promising.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [blender](https://www.blender.org/features/)?

----- Edit -----

Looking more into it, Blender now only support exporting .X files with a script that needs to be activated via User Preferences, see [this forum post](https://web.archive.org/web/20151125045441/https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=19681).

You could try converting your .x files into another format to import them fo the tool you want, [Milkshape](https://web.archive.org/web/20140820143851/http://chumbalum.swissquake.ch:80/ms3d/index.html) may work.

----- Edit -----

After looking even more into it, I see that people reccommend [TrueSpace 7.6](https://web.archive.org/web/20120117022245/http://www.caligari.com/downloads.html) which is now completely free and should allow you to import .x files.

If you don't like the modeller after that, you can just export to a different format and use your favourite modeller.

----- Edit -----

After managing to find [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7421/Conv3ds-exe-Utility-Helper) on CodeProject, DirectX apparently once provided a tool to convert from .x to .3ds. The link (not tested) should be a Dx8 Extras pack that comes with the conv3ds.exe utility. [Here it is](http://download.microsoft.com/download/DirectX/extras/8.1b/W982KMeXP/EN-US/DX81b_SDK_Extras.exe), good luck.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion and for the willing to help. Checking TrueSpace.

Comment: @Zéiksz : Any luck?

Comment: No. Took some time with this, but 1; milkshape loaded textures bad (even if the preview was just fine), and no animations. 2; TrueSpace did not load .x at all. (Checked tiny.x shipped with directx sdk too). Now just reading forums if there is a fix for that TrueSpace thing..

Comment: The support for .x imports seems horribly lacking in almost all modelling software. You may unfortunately have to create an importer yourself, or try to donwload a converter.

Comment: @Zéiksz : I added a tool I found to my answer.

Comment: Marking this as good answer, since it is very closest (for my goal at least) and working. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No probs, glad it's working, how about a little up vote too? xD

Comment: Wanted to, had no 15 rep so far. Doing so as possible.

Answer (score 0):

[Blender's website](http://www.blender.org/) lists DirectX as a supported file type

Comment: For exporting, can not import (or for 2.49b and pre can not import properly).

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) allows for .x importing (it ships with the import script)

Comment: Top version for this is 2.49b. Can import one mesh and no animations. Useless.